# displaying values in specific places only when an option is chosen

Tags: php, html, css

I just started learning web development earlier this week, and I was wondering how I can display specific values in table, after a certain option is chosen. For instance, assume I chose "LW" from the drop list, then I want in the first cell to see "RD." However if I changed my input to "SW", I want to see "RS" in that place instead. Below is what I've written so far and where "that place" is.
TIA

```
  <html>
    <style>
    p {
      font-size:30px;font-family:Arial Narrow;font-style:italic:;color:black;
    }
    
    </style>
    <header>
    <center>
    <p> ALGORITHM </p>
    </center>
    </header>
    <body>
      INSTRUCTION
       <form action = "" method = "POST">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td><br></td>
            <td><output name = "1st"></td>   // here
            <td>2nd</td>
            <td>3rd</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
      <select name="inst" id="inst">
        <option value="LW">LW</option>
        <option value="SW">SW</option>
        <option value="BEQ">BEQ</option>
        <option value="JALR">JALR</option>
        <option value="RET">RET</option>
        <option value="ADD">ADD</option>
        <option value="NEG">NEG</option>
        <option value="ADDI">ADDI</option>
        <option value="MULL">MULL</option>
        <option value="MULH">MULH</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
       <input type = "number" name="p1">
     </td>
     <td>
       <input type = "number" name="p2">
     </td>
     <td>
       <input type = "number" name="p3">
     </td>
     <td>
     </tr>
    </table>
       <button type = "submit" name = "shoot"> compute </button>
      </form>
    <?php
    
     ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You need JavaScript unless you mean update the cell after submit.

Comment: Thanks for replying...........Can I just get the value that will be selected from the drop list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use javascript's onchange function to update the data after you have changed the select box.

To do what you want, you may use something like:

```
function updatex(){
var e = document.getElementById("inst");
if (e.value=="LW"){
document.getElementById('captionx').innerHTML="RD";
  }

if (e.value=="SW"){
document.getElementById('captionx').innerHTML="RS";
  }
}
```

So the whole code will be:

```
<html>
    <style>
    p {
      font-size:30px;font-family:Arial Narrow;font-style:italic:;color:black;
    }
    
    </style>
    <header>


<script>
function updatex(){
var e = document.getElementById("inst");
if (e.value=="LW"){
document.getElementById('captionx').innerHTML="RD";
  }

if (e.value=="SW"){
document.getElementById('captionx').innerHTML="RS";
  }
}
</script>  

    <center>
    <p> ALGORITHM </p>
    </center>
    </header>
    <body>
      INSTRUCTION
       <form action = "" method = "POST">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td><br></td>
            <td><div id=captionx></div></td>
            <td>2nd</td>
            <td>3rd</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
      <select name="inst" id="inst" onchange="javascript:updatex();">
        <option value="">Please select</option>
        <option value="LW">LW</option>
        <option value="SW">SW</option>
        <option value="BEQ">BEQ</option>
        <option value="JALR">JALR</option>
        <option value="RET">RET</option>
        <option value="ADD">ADD</option>
        <option value="NEG">NEG</option>
        <option value="ADDI">ADDI</option>
        <option value="MULL">MULL</option>
        <option value="MULH">MULH</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
       <input type = "number" name="p1">
     </td>
     <td>
       <input type = "number" name="p2">
     </td>
     <td>
       <input type = "number" name="p3">
     </td>
     <td>
     </tr>
    </table>
       <button type = "submit" name = "shoot"> compute </button>
      </form>
    <?php
    
     ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot...I will make sure to learn JavaScript too